# next.js remove out folder from url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, next.js

I have a project built with next js framework, this is my first deploy for this tecnology.
The server is shared with other services so my project must reside in a subfolder.

The server directory structure is as below:

```
www
  |_ myproject
             |_out
```

(out is the result of npm build)

Resulting url is:

https://www.myserver.com/myproject/out/index.html

I can't change VirtualHost, so only using htaccess, I need that if a user point to:

https://www.myserver.com/myproject/

Apache respond with the content of /out/ folder without showing it on the url

So, https://www.myserver.com/myproject/index.html must return the content of https://www.myserver.com/myproject/out/index.html also all path must be rewritten without showing the real path.

Everything without redirect, in a transparent manner..

Is this possible?